# How can I use a Github token for more than 24 hours?

Tags: github, continuous-integration

We have a Github CI action that can sometimes run longer than 24 hours. However, [according to the Github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) after 24 hours the `GITHUB_TOKEN` expires. In the Github workflow run log I get the error message *"Unable to extend GITHUB_TOKEN expiration time due to: GITHUB_TOKEN has expired."* This is a bummer because we need this token at the end of this lengthy CI action, i.e. after these 24 hours.

Is there a way to extend the lifetime of the `GITHUB_TOKEN` for a CI workflow?
Or if not, what other options do I have for such CI actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to extend the lifetime of GITHUB_TOKEN. And in this case, if you cannot make your workflow run faster (or maybe you can by using [larger runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/using-larger-runners)) you need to use [PAT token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) instead.

This has a big disadvantage - you need to refresh it on your own. Creating a token valid for a long time would be a potential security issue. But otherwise, you would be forced to refresh it very often.